# Working of Firebase.on() and $firebaseArrayVariable.$watch()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I'm using AngularFire 1.2.0 and Firebase 2.2.4

I have 2 applications, one is for uploading data to Firebase, and the other one is used for displaying the data in realtime.

The application that handles the uploading of data to Firebase is made in C# using [FireSharp](https://github.com/ziyasal/FireSharp) Library. FireSharp uses REST API behind the scene. It uploads data and generate unique keys on Firebase for every child and node.

The second application is used to display the data. It is made using AngularFire, AngularJS, and Firebase. My problem is that, I'm confused how to use events like `child_added` so that I can listen to new records and update my display application.

**Note: First application continuously uploads data every 4 to 5 seconds**

Below code is not getting fired even if my application is pushing data continuously.

```
  var dashObject = new Firebase("https://URL/DataNode");
        dashObject.on("child_added", function (newChild, previousSiblingChild) {
            console.log("new child");
            console.log(newChild);

            });
```

And I have also tried the code below. This works and it's logging data to the console, but it only shows the keys of the new child if `child_added` is fired. I also want the data of the new child, not only the keys.

```
var testQUery = dashObject.orderByChild("victim_IncidentDate").startAt('1446577577474').endAt('14463222357474');

    var vicData = $firebaseArray(testQUery);
    vicData.$watch(function (event) { console.log(event)});
```

Below is code from C# application which uploads data and `lists` variable is populated using `EntityFrameWork 6.0`. Code for populating `lists` variable is not shown,I just shows decalaration here to inform you people about its `dataType`.
`IFirebaseClient` is used to intialize client

```
 using FireSharp.Interfaces;
    using FireSharp.Config;
    using FireSharp;
    using FireSharp.Response;
    using FireSharp.EventStreaming;
    using FireSharp.Extensions;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;

List<MyCustomClassDataContract> lists=null;
    IFirebaseClient client = null;

for(int i=0;i<lists.length;i++)
{
PushResponse Riskresponse = await client.PushAsync("RiskCatDetail", lists[i]);
string RiskID = Riskresponse.Result.name;
```

}

Comment: `child_added` will only fire if *new data is added* to a list. Can you add the code that uploads the data?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen see my updated Post, Data is uploading successfully from `c#` application

Comment: Hmmm.... I don't immediately see what's wrong: pushing sounds like it will create a new child. Is there any way you can set up a jsfiddle/jsbin that reproduces the read problem?

Comment: Alternatively, log with `testQUery.on('value', function(snapshot) { console.log(snapshot.val()); })`. That will likely fire for each change.

Comment: jsfiddle will not support C# syntax,I think. Firsharp uses REST API of firebase behind the scenes according to their documentation.Its PushAsync do the same as $add() do.i.e adds data at specified postion with random generated firebase  unique key

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen and one more thing. is child_added gives on child unique key? not its all the data?